# Should I always order the data vector in ascending order before using "summary" function in R?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics

Should I always **order** the data vector in ascending order before using `summary` function in R?

Or should I just apply `summary` function directly on raw data vector?

Comment: In general, R does not require sorting to perform operations (in contrast to e.g. Stata).  In fact, life is generally easier if you do not sort.

Comment: Stata typically only requires prior sorting when the operation depends on the sort order. That should not surprise.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to order the data first.

Try `summary(1:5)` and `summary(5:1)`, and you will always get the same `min`, `max`, `mean` and `quartiles`.